# How to debug EC2 instances where custom health checks fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, health-monitoring

I have an auto-scaling group with EC2 that implement a [custom health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/healthcheck.html#as-configure-healthcheck).
From time to time, the health check fails and instances are terminated and replaced.

The health check itself is implemented as a shell script that runs on the instances. If it detects problems, it will inform the auto scaling group via the AWS API:

```
aws autoscaling set-instance-health --instance-id $instance --health-status Unhealthy
```

The problem is only that I have no information about what check failed, beside the notification:

> Cause: At 2017-06-13T09:11:47Z an instance was taken out of service in response to a user health-check

What is the recommended way to debug these type of problems. Is there a way to make AWS only stop instances and not terminate them, so their disk state could be inspected?

---

(First I thought about "enable termination protection", but from my understanding this will not make a difference, here. Autoscaling group will still terminate the instances when the shutdown was requested by a failing custom health check.)

Comment: Is your situation an Auto Scaling group that is using an ELB Health Check?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No, it is a custom health check. I have a local script running that when it detects that something is wrong, will inform the autoscaling group via the AWS API ("aws autoscaling set-instance-health")

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'll updated my question, so this information is now covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `set-instance-health` command tells Auto Scaling that the instance is unhealthy and needs to be replaced. Auto Scaling will then terminate the unhealthy instance and launch a new instance to replace it.

If you wish to perform forensic analysis on an unhealthy instance, remove it from the Auto Scaling group with the [`aws autoscaling detach-instances` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/detach-instances.html):

> Removes one or more instances from the specified Auto Scaling group. After the instances are detached, you can **manage them independent of the Auto Scaling group**.
>
> If you do not specify the option to decrement the desired capacity, Auto Scaling launches instances to **replace** the ones that are detached.
>
> If there is a Classic Load Balancer attached to the Auto Scaling group, the instances are deregistered from the load balancer. If there are target groups attached to the Auto Scaling group, the instances are deregistered from the target groups.

So, instead of calling `set-instance-health`, call `detach-instances` (and optionally replace it). You can then debug the instance. If you wish to send it back into service, use `aws autoscaling attach-instances`.